Deciding if a regular language is empty can be done in polytime but deciding if it does not accept {0,1}* is not?
In my class we have discussed the fact that, given a representation $\langle R\rangle$ of a regular expression $R$, we can decide whether it accepts any string by first finding an equivalent NFA, and then seeing if there is a path from the start to an accepting vertex.  This can be done in polynomial time.
However, we have also said that it is NP-hard to determine whether $L(R)\ne\{0,1\}^*$.  That is to say, the language $\{\langle R\rangle: R \text{ is a RE and } L(R)\ne\{0,1\}^*\}$ is NP-hard.
I'm having a hard time reconciling these two facts.  To decide whether $L(R)\ne \{0,1\}^*$, it is equivalent to decide whether $\overline{L(R)} \ne \emptyset$, which we can do in polynomial time.  I'm sure there's something I'm misunderstanding but I can't tell what.

Deciding emptiness of a regular expression is easy, but constructing the complement is not.
The paper Succinctness of the Complement and Intersection of Regular Expressions
by Gelade and Neven (arXiv:0802.2869, published at STACS 2008) suggests this construction (from regexp to regexp of the complement) is doubly exponential. See Thm 4.1(2).

Let $\Sigma$ be a four-letter alphabet. For every $n \in \mathbb N$,
there is a regular expression $r_n$ of size $\mathscr O(n)$ such that
any regular expression $r$ defining  $Σ^* \setminus L(r_n)$ is of size
at least $2^{2^n}$.


Interesting -- I hope I can ask a follow-up question then.  Can you not (1) get the NFA of R, (2) negate this by flipping accepting states, (3) use this to decide if the complement is empty?

Well, I should probably say "Why can you not ..." since if it were that easy I'm sure nobody would be publishing papers on the topic.

Flipping accepting states in an NFA does not yield the complement of the original language. The only dependable construction for complementation is via the subset construction that will construct a DFA. The new automaton in the worst case will have a single exponantial number of states. Even if we just consider NFAs for language and its complement the worst case will be exponential, see  https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/10459/4287  (I will probably move this to the main answer, but it is late now.)
